# CSS anchor inline-block misaligned

Tags: html, css

I have this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BAw5F/). Can someone explain, why is the anchor position misaligned relative to its siblings? I know I can correct it with position relative and negaitve top offset, but I don't understand, why it is like this in the first place.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <a href="">Some link</a>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    height: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.container .left {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 80px;
    padding: 0;
}

.container .right {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 80px;
    padding: 0;
}

.container a {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason of this behaviour is due to the absence of text inside your `.left` and `.right` elements.

By default inline-block elements have `vertical-align: baseline`, but since you have empty elements there's no baseline, so they will be automatically aligned to the `parent` baseline (if you add some text inside them — even a `&nbsp;` — you would istantly solve the problem)

In order to prevent this behaviour you could also set a common `vertical-align` to all `.container` children.

Comment: Thanks! Although all the answers fixed the issue, yours actually provided an explanation that I was after.

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to `.container a`

This wil align the anchor with the divs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `vertical-align` property when you are declaring an `inline-block`.

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BAw5F/3/)**

**The CSS Change:**

```
.container a {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use so many Option

**1**. Remove `Display:inline-block` and add `float:left`

Here the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BAw5F/5/)

**2**. Use css `vertical-align:top`

Here [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BAw5F/7/)